# Which methodology for calculating SNR is appropriate for this image?

Tags: image, signals, noise

I was trying to find snr for a set of images that I have but my two methodologies of doing so creates two different answers and I'm not sure which is right. I was wondering if one of them is just straight up the wrong way of doing this or if neither way is correct?

I am trying to characterize the snr of a set of images that I'm processing. I have 1 set of data with images and darkfields. From these pieces of data I subtracted the darkfield from the image and got "corrected_images".

So since I know snr is (mean of signal)/(std of noise), in my first methodology I was working with the corrected image and background noise image and I just took the mean of every pixel on the spectrum (from the corrected image) with a value greater than 1 for signal and the general std for the background noise image as my values. the plot for this methodology is in blue.

In my second methodology I used a single uncorrected image and basically considered every pixel above 50 as signal and every pixel below 50 as noise.This gives us the orange values for snr.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Spyder Editor

This is a temporary script file.
"""

from PIL import Image
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

import os
signals=[]
name = r"interpolating_streaks/corrected"
name2 = r"interpolating_streaks/averages"
file = os.listdir(name)
file2 =  os.listdir(name2)
wv1=[]
signal = []
snr = []
noise = []
x=0
for i in file:
    wv=(i[:3])
    wv1.append(wv)
    corrected_image = Image.open(name+"/"+i) #opens the image
    streak= np.array(corrected_image)
    dark_image = Image.open(name2+'/d'+wv+'_averaged.tif')
    dark = np.array(dark_image)
    darkavg = dark[:][:].mean(axis=0)
    avg= streak[:][:].mean(axis=0)
    for i in avg:
        if i >= 1:
            signal.append(i)
    noiser = np.std(darkavg)
    signalr = np.mean(signal)
    snr.append(signalr/noiser)
plt.plot(wv1,snr)
signal = []
noise = []
snr = []
for i in file2:
    if(i[0] !='d'):
        image = Image.open(name2+'/' + i )
        im = np.array(image)
        im_avg = im[:][:].mean(axis=0)
        for i in im_avg:
            if i <= 50:
                noise.append(i)
            else: 
                signal.append(i)
        snr.append(np.mean(signal)/np.std(noise))
plt.plot(wv1,snr)
```

I would expect the snr values to be the same , and I know for my camera the snr has to be below 45 dB (but also I'm pretty sure this methodology for snr doesnt output decibels)

here are my current results
![1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVlZm.jpg

Comment: Removed the tag <[processing](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/processing/info)>. [Processing](https://processing.org/) is a flexible software sketchbook and a language for learning how to code within the context of the visual arts.